# Control Panel Date Format

Tags: control-panel

I am based in the UK Where we format dates for 17th May 2018 like so:

17/5/18

Is it possible for the Craft Control Panel to use a specified format when listing entries' post date / expiry date etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Craft 2**

The Date/Time formatting in the Control Panel is based on what locale you're using when you're viewing the Control Panel.

If you have `eb_gb` as a locale defined under Settings->Sites->Locales, then you can go to your user account settings and set your "Preferred Locale" settings to "British English" and you'll get the DD/MM/YYYY format.

**Craft 3**

The locale you're site is currently set to and the language your viewing the Control Panel in are now separate concepts.  If you go to your user account, click "Preferences", you'll see a "Language" dropdown, which controls the date/time formatting of the Control Panel for you.

If you want to set this globally for users that haven’t yet set their preferred language then you can use the [`defaultCpLanguage`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#defaultcplanguage) config setting. This is also useful when migrating a site from Craft 2.x to 3.x as all existing users won’t have set that preference and it will default to `en-US`.

Comment: I'm on Craft 3, with the site set to `en-gb`, however showing the date fields in the entry list in the CP still shows the M/D/Y format, not D/M/Y.

Comment: @AdamMenczykowski updated answer for Craft 3

Comment: Is there a way to force all users to use one format?

Comment: Same issue as Adam. I'm set to GB but it's still showing in the American date system. I find it remarkable that this and per-user timezones are still things unavailable in Craft...

Comment: I'd like to have the interface language to be english. date format like `yyyy-mm-dd` or even `dd.mm.yyyy` (German). Is that possible?

Comment: I agree with Frank L; these would be nice to be able to define separately. As an American-born living in a country that uses European-style dates, I've had it with both sets of idiotic systems and have been using `YYYY-MM-DD` for the past 20 years wherever possible, which precludes any possibility of confusion (it's also an ISO standard and the official W3C date format for the web, probably for the same reasons).

Comment: +1 for a possibility to set time/date format seperately from the language. I'm very surprised that's currently not possible. I live in The Netherlands, have all my interfaces on English, but I'd like to view the timeformat in 24h notation and date with day-month-year...